# Load multiple excel files in multiple tables using single connection in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I am loading multiple excel files into multiple SQL server table.

these excel files are the city, state, etc. Is it possible to create a single flat file connection? currently, I am creating for city and state and for other src. attached the screenshot for better understanding.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If all of the source files are structured *exactly* the same (number of columns, data types, header rows, etc.), it would be *possible* to re-use a single flat file connection.

In general, though, the best practice is to create a connection for each file. It makes the package easier to understand in a year or two when you, or someone else, has to open it up again to fix or update it. It will also make it much easier to fix later if one or more of the files ends up changing (new columns, etc.).

Comment: Further to Eric's answers here is the link that shows how to do it: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4165/how-to-read-data-from-multiple-excel-files-with-sql-server-integration-services/